# Why is my food bar not going down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm new to Minecraft and I'm really enjoying it.  I play every day, mining, jumping around and all that stuff, but then I noticed my food bar is not going down. What would cause that?

Comment: On vanilla, if the food bar exists and is not going down, that means you are in Peaceful mode.

Comment: Or Creative Mode.

Comment: In Creative Mode there is no food bar at all.

Answer (score 10):

You are in Creative mode or on Peaceful difficulty

> Creative Mode
>
> Creative mode strips away the survival aspects of Minecraft and allows
> players to easily create and destroy structures.

[Minecraft Wiki - Creative Mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creative)

> Peaceful Difficulty
>
> The Food Bar never depletes and players cannot eat anything except
> Golden Apples, unless the player has switched to Peaceful when their
> Food Bar was below the maximum.

[Minecraft Wiki - Peaceful Difficulty](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty)

Comment: Not necessarily, could also be in peaceful mode.

Comment: In fact, peaceful difficulty is significantly more likely.